# Have image in the navigation bar

Tags: php, html, css

I have a navbar.php that is called in the index.php.
The navbar looks and works fine but in one of the tabs I just have the word Logo and I wanted to replace it with an actual image. Just like many websites have it. I've seen many people using bootstrap however I'm not familiar with that at all. What is wrong with the PHP and CSS I'm trying to use?

Path of navbar.php
project/file.css

Path of image.png
project/img/image.png

navbar.php

```
<div class="navbar">
    <a class="logo" href="#" img src="img/image.png"></a>
    <div class="navbar-right">
        <a class="active" href="../index.php">Home</a>
        <a href="../include/about.php">About</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

style.css

```
/*Logo*/
.navbar a.logo{
  display:block;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background: url(img/image.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem with the HTML markup is here

```
<a class="logo" href="#" img src="img/image.png"></a>
```

By the above markup, you are saying that a hyperlink should be an image or should act as an image or something like that. This doesn't make sense.

What you can do is you can visit this website:
http://www.icons8.com and search your icons accordingly. You can also download it and store it in your system folder.

Once you have done this, you can write the above code as follows:

```
 <div class="navbar">
 <a class="logo" href="#"><span><img src="yourImgURLHere"/></span> </a>
 <div class="navbar-right">
 <a class="active" href="../index.php">Home</a>
 <a href="../include/about.php">About</a>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm not sure what you meant with the icons but the span tags have solved my issue, now I've just got one more slight problem. Them image seems quite scaled down or the padding? is big around it. How could I get it to fill the bar as big as it can ? Here's what it looks like now https://imgur.com/a/vPjZkQ0

Comment: To avoid any confusion, you can visit this link and select what type of navbar you want. You can also copy the code by clicking 'Try It' button.
https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_navbar.asp

I am sure this will solve your issue of padding(or even margin).